# How to sort list using grep to show the number of unique occurrences based on a predefined list?

Tags: awk, grep

So let's say I have a list that looks like this

**example.txt:**

```
2010-01-06 15:03:14 57.55.24.13 user1
2010-01-07 20:02:14 69.54.12.36 user2
2010-01-08 12:34:34 127.21.159.2 user3
2010-01-08 02:43:45 116.40.11.179 user1
```

The list has a bunch of given users and the ip addresses they used. What I want to do is find the number of unique IP addresses each user has logged in from. So in the previous example, user1 would return the value of 2. However, if user1 logged in again from 116.40.11.179 the result would still be 2 since it's not a unique ip.

I've tried making a list of usernames.

**userlist.txt:**

```
user1
user2
user3
```

Then I try passing it to grep with something like

```
grep example.txt | uniq -c | wc -l < userlist.txt
```

but that obviously isn't working out so well. Any ideas?

Comment: Please do mention the expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 The output would be (# of occurences) user so for my code example it'd be user1 2 or 2 user1 whichever works better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
{
    u = $4
    ip = $3
    if (!s[u,ip]++)
        cnt[u]++
}
END {
    for (u in cnt)
        print u, cnt[u]
}
' input.file
```

Outputs

```
user1 2
user2 1
user3 1
```

Comment: `if (!((u, ip) in s)) {
        s[u, ip];
        cnt[u]++
    }` would more commonly/idiomatically be written as `if (!seen[u,ip]++) {
        cnt[u]++
    }`

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
!seen[$NF OFS $(NF-1)]++{
  user[$NF]++
}
END{
  for(key in user){
    print key,user[key]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
user1 2                                                                                                                       
user2 1                                                                                                                       
user3 1
```

Comment: The other persons answer also worked but they posted it sooner. Not really sure how either actually does the job.

Comment: Ryan Ravinder and @slitvinov's solutions are identical except that slitvinov uses a couple of variables to hold the values from $NF and $(NF-1), puts the test/condition inside the action area instead of in the condition area, and doesn't use the idiomatic `!seen[keys]++` for the test.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for arrays of arrays:

```
$ awk '{usrs_ips[$4][$3]} END{for (usr in usrs_ips) print usr, length(usrs_ips[usr])}' file
user1 2
user2 1
user3 1
```

With an awk that supports length(array):

```
$ sort -k4,4 file | awk '
    $4 != prev {if (NR>1) print prev, length(ips); prev=$4; delete ips }
    { ips[$3] }
    END { print prev, length(ips) }
'
user1 2
user2 1
user3 1
```

With any awk:

```
$ sort -k4,4 file | awk '
    $4 != prev { if (NR>1) print prev, cnt; prev=$4; delete seen; cnt=0 }
    !seen[$3]++ { cnt++ }
    END { print prev, cnt }
'
user1 2
user2 1
user3 1
```

Those last 2 have the benefit over the first one and the other solutions posted so far of not storing every user+ip combination in memory but that would only matter if your input file was huge.

Answer (score 1):

The tool to perform this operation is **uniq**. You need to apply **uniq** twice: a first one to time to group the entries of **example.txt** by user and IP, a second one for counting.

So no need to recode it in AWK, even if this can be done in a very beautiful way. I will use AWK however for reordering fields:

```
awk '{print $4, $3}' example.txt | sort | uniq | awk '{print $1}' | uniq -c
```

No need for a separate **userlist.txt** file.

Comment: `sort | uniq` = `sort -u` and you could reduce the pipes and calls to awk further if you sort first with `sort -k4,4 -k3,3 -u file | awk '{print $4}' | uniq -c`.

Comment: In fact you don't need awk at all: `sort -k4,4 -k3,3 -u file | cut -d' ' -f 4 | uniq -c` would be more efficient since `cut` does far less work per input line than `awk` does. Nice approach, btw.

Comment: @EdMorton: This is great! By the way, I didn't expect you to propose an awk-free solution. I used awk for the sake of readability.

Comment: I just use whatever tool is best suited for the job (sed, grep, cut, whatever), it's just that when people are posting questions here about manipulating text it's usually for something non-trival and then the best solution is often awk. So you're getting a skewed view of the tools I use from the answers I provide to questions that are usually tagged with awk :-). In this case I just didn't think of the `sort | cut | uniq` approach first!

Answer (score 0):

A non-`awk` example, using GNU [`datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/), a really useful tool for doing operations of groups of columnar data like this:

```
$ datamash -Ws -g4 countunique 3 < example.txt
user1   2
user2   1
user3   1
```

For each group with the same value in the 4th column, it prints the number of unique occurrences of values in the third column.